# Make a folder with an empty file with a specific name in each subfolder

Tags: python, for-loop, os.walk

A column in a csv has a couple of numbers in each row:

```
col
12
14
11
..
```

I have made a folder for every row with that name with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = ..
fn = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\xlfile\asc.csv',header = None)
for i in df["col"].astype(str):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, i))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, i)) #this has to be make in the last folder
    #file from a certain path to be copied
```

Now I want to make a folder that has a specific file in every one of these folders.

folder name : `new_f`
 and the file is located in a path

```
path: ...
```

How do I make a folder named `new_f` and make a copy of that file in that path to every folder made?

**UPDATE**:
Further explanation

What the answer below did but its just that these files need to be in one more folder too.

Example:

the folders now are after your code in the answer:

```
12 // file.shp
14 // file.shp
```

while they should be

```
12 // new_folder// file.shp annd file.shx and file.dbf

path = 'this path has the above files scattered so maybe it can read what files are there and copy them to each of the folders as said.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shutil` to copy the file into your directories:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from shutil import copy

path = ..
file_names = ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt', 'text3.txt']  # replace with your file you want copied

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\xlfile\asc.csv',header = None)
for i in df["col"].astype(str):
    dest = os.path.join(path, i)
    os.mkdir(dest)
    dest = os.path.join(path, i, 'new_folder')
    os.mkdir(dest)
    for file_name in file_names:
        source = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        copy(source, dest)
```

This produces 3 folders called 11, 12, and 14, and each contains a copy of the file text.txt.

Comment: What if there are more than one txt to be copied?

Comment: How do you determine which text file goes into which folder?  Is it based on name?

Comment: I have updated the answer to copy multiple files into each folder, and to create "new_folder" under each of the numbered folders.

Comment: The part where you make also a folder in all these folders and you put these files in is missing. Can you add this please?This throws them directly in those folders.

Comment: You refer to the new  folder before its creation and throws error `The system cannot find the path specified:`

Comment: Thanks that helped me.

Comment: Can help in another question? I will post it now, I will give you a notice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341241/pair-files-based-on-the-subfolders-name