# Pair files based on the subfolders name?

Tags: python, loops

This checks a file from the new path and appends them to an empty in file in an old one.

Most of the code is ready its just the connection that is missing:

example the new path has this structure:

```
r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\mainfolder\PST_TO_APPEND\1211\file"
```

and the old:

```
r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\mainfolder\PST_PROTYPO\1211\file"
```

How to make it so all the files will be paired with based on the code on their subfolder?

Here is my code that works fine but can't deal with many files at once.

Just help with the connection above all the rest is ok.

```
    import os
... import shutil
... 
... old_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\mainfolder\PST_PROTYPO"
... new_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\mainfolder\PST_TO_APPEND"


... #This will find the matching shape files and pass them to arcpy.Append_management():
... #part2
... 
... import os
... import arcpy
... 
... for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace=new_path, datatype="FeatureClass"):
...     for filename in file_names:
...         new_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
...         folder = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(new_file_path))
...         old_file_path = os.path.join(old_path, folder, filename)
...         if os.path.exists(old_file_path):
...             arcpy.Append_management([new_file_path], old_file_path, "NO_TEST") # appends new to old shp <------if wrong swap the new with the old file path
...
```